# Generar un Array con JS/Jquery desde una tabla guardada en una variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, table

Tengo la siguiente tabla guardada en una variable

```
var table = '<table>
   <tr><td>Test1</td><td>Test2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Test3</td><td>Test4</td></tr>
</table>';
```

¿hay posibilidad de hacer una iteracción por cada tr e ir guardando los td con JS?

Comment: Nos mostrarías por favor lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías conseguirlo así:

- Crear un elemento `jQuery` con el `html` de la variable (*eg: `$(table)`*).
- Luego sobre dicho elemento utilizar [`.find('td')`](https://api.jquery.com/find/#find-selector) para obtener todos los `td`.
- Luego la función [`.map(fn)`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) para obtener de cada `td`, por ejemplo, el texto.
- Finalmente [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get) para obtener un arreglo con el resultado.

```js
var table = `<table>
   <tr><td>Test1</td><td>Test2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Test3</td><td>Test4</td></tr>
</table>`;

let arr = $(table).find('td').map((i, e) => e.innerText).get();
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr").each(function(index, element){ 
     console.log(index); 
     console.log(element)
})
```

De esta manera recorres los `tr`

puedes guardarlo en `JS` como mejor te convenga.

---

Si lo que necesitas es un simple `array` con los `td`:

```
var temp = [];

$("tr td").each(function(index, element){ 
     temp.push($(this).html());
})
```

Esto te almacena el contenido del cada `td` en el array `temp`.